# Heroku is unable to authorize Stormpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, stormpath

I'm trying to host my application on Heroku. It uses Stormpath for user management, specifically `stormpath-sdk-angularjs` and `stormpath-sdk-express`. I've loaded my Stormpath API credentials onto Heroku's config variables and include them into the Stormpath middleware on my server like this:

```
var stormpathExpressSdk = require('stormpath-sdk-express');
var spMiddleware = stormpathExpressSdk.createMiddleware({
    cache: 'memory',
    apiKeyId: process.env.STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID,
    apiKeySecret: process.env.STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET,
    appHref: process.env.STORMPATH_APP_HREF,
    secretKey: process.env.STORMPATH_SECRET_KEY,
    ...
    (other options)
    ...
});

spMiddleware.attachDefaults(app);
app.use(spMiddleware.authenticate);

// Includes all routes
var router = require('./router')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

The error I keep getting from `heroku logs` is:

> ResourceError: HTTP 401, Stormpath 401 (http://www.stormpath.com/docs/quickstart/connect): Authentication with a valid API Key is required.]
>
> 2015-09-23T13:54:04.209032+00:00 app[web.1]:   userMessage: 'Authentication required.'

However I know my credentials are correct because I'm able to start my app locally. I even hard coded the API credentials, copied straight from Heroku config, to make sure and I'm able to start locally. Why doesn't this work?

**Edit:**

Middleware used before the Stormpath middleware.

```
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

Comment: confirm that `process.env` has all the properties and values correct?

Comment: @charlietfl yes I did that, and it does have the correct values.

Comment: Is anything else in your Express app trying to modify the request headers?

Comment: @Nate Barbettini I edited the post to included the middleware used before Stormpath in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Heroku to authorize Stormpath by [adding it on](https://addons.heroku.com/stormpath) to my app in Heroku. After adding it on, Heroku provided me with a Stormpath account with different API credentials and I used these in the middleware. I'm not sure if this is the only way, but my original Stormpath account had little configuration porting those settings to the new one was quick.